# Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object in C# Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a method that takes in a form submission and submissions answers. 
In order to save the submission answers to the database; I need to set the submission answers with a reference ID to the submission.

I am attempting to do this but receiving the error listed in the title: 
"Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object" and I am unsure why.

I've tried to save everything to the database before adjusting any values; but that doesn't seem to help. I get another error saying that I am attempting to remove a foreign key.

I imagine this is a db context issue.

```
public FormSubmission AddSubmission(FormSubmission submission, List<FormSubmissionAnswer> submissionAnswers, int CustomerId, string CustomerName)
    {
        Form form = GetForm(submission.FormId.ToString());
        //set submission values
        submission.FormTitle = form.Title1;
        submission.DateSubmitted = DateTime.Now;
        if (CustomerId > 0)
            submission.PSMCustomerId = CustomerId;
        submission.CustomerName = CustomerName;
        base.SubscriptionDB.FormSubmissions.InsertOnSubmit(submission);
        base.SubscriptionDB.SubmitChanges();

        //need to update the submission answers FormSubmissionId            
        foreach (FormSubmissionAnswer answer in submissionAnswers)
            answer.FormSubmissionId = submission.Id; //erroring here

      base.SubscriptionDB.FormSubmissionAnswers.InsertAllOnSubmit(submissionAnswers);
        base.SubscriptionDB.SubmitChanges();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```html
foreach (FormSubmissionAnswer answer in submissionAnswers)
            answer.FormSubmissionId = submission.Id; //erroring here
```

Try

```html
foreach (FormSubmissionAnswer answer in submissionAnswers)
            submission.FormSubmissionAnswers.Add(answer);
```

In the end call
base.SubscriptionDB.SubmitChanges();

base.SubscriptionDB.FormSubmissions.InsertOnSubmit(submission);
        base.SubscriptionDB.SubmitChanges(); //Remove from FormSubmission instead use at only one time. This should solve your problem.

Your final code should be like below

```html
Form form = GetForm(submission.FormId.ToString());
        //set submission values
        submission.FormTitle = form.Title1;
        submission.DateSubmitted = DateTime.Now;
        if (CustomerId > 0)
            submission.PSMCustomerId = CustomerId;
        submission.CustomerName = CustomerName;
        base.SubscriptionDB.FormSubmissions.InsertOnSubmit(submission);
        
        //need to update the submission answers FormSubmissionId            
        foreach (FormSubmissionAnswer answer in submissionAnswers)
            submission.FormSubmissionAnswers.Add(answer); 
   
        base.SubscriptionDB.SubmitChanges();
```

I assume that you have proper entity relations.

Comment: Good deal. I knew I was doing something silly; but I just couldn't see it. 
Thanks for the assist!

Answer (score 2):

What do your FormSubmission and FormSubmissionAnswer entities look like?  I assume that FormSubmission has some kind of IEnumerable property to represent the relationship between the two.  Try adding the answer objects to the list before doing the initial submit changes:

```
submission.CustomerName = CustomerName;
submission.FormSubmissionAnswers.AddRange(submissionAnswers);
base.SubscriptionDB.FormSubmissions.InsertOnSubmit(submission);
base.SubscriptionDB.SubmitChanges();
```

I believe EF should automatically generate the PK's and correctly assign the correct FK's as well.  Then you wouldn't even need to do:

```
//need to update the submission answers FormSubmissionId            
foreach (FormSubmissionAnswer answer in submissionAnswers)
    answer.FormSubmissionId = submission.Id; //erroring here

base.SubscriptionDB.FormSubmissionAnswers.InsertAllOnSubmit(submissionAnswers);
base.SubscriptionDB.SubmitChanges();
```